# PostgreSQL: Adding Where clause to nested JSONB query

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm trying to return the "value": "Brunswick" WHERE "language": "en"
from the JSON string bellow

This returns the first in the list I don't know the index in the actual data

```
SELECT id, names->'common'->0->>'value' AS name FROM test;
```

Where as this returns 1, null

```
SELECT id,names @@ '$.common[*].value' AS en_name  FROM test
WHERE names @@ '$.common[*].language == "en"'
```

The above from here
[how to query for values in a deep nested json array in Postresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72718535/how-to-query-for-values-in-a-deep-nested-json-array-in-postresql?rq=3)

Also tried jsonb_path_query from [Postgres find in jsonb nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59744500/postgres-find-in-jsonb-nested-array)

Table with Cut down JSON string

```
    INSERT INTO test(id,names) VALUES(1,'{
  "short": null,
  "common": [
    {
      "value": "برونشوايغ",
      "language": "ar"
    },
    {
      "value": "Brunswick",
      "language": "en"
    }
  
  ]
}');
```

Here's my https://dbfiddle.uk/UiXTG8Vo

The plan is to update the en_name column with the returned value

Comment: "*Also tried jsonb_path_query from Postgres find in jsonb nested array*" - what exactly did you try?

Comment: At the bottom of the fiddle `SELECT id,'common'->>'name_value' AS en_name, 'common'->>'language' AS language
FROM test,
  JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(names->'common') AS common
  JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(common->'value') as name_value,
  JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(common->'language') AS language
WHERE language = 'en';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only a single level of array nesting, so you need `jsonb_array_elements` only once:

```
SELECT id, name->>'value' AS en_name
FROM test, jsonb_array_elements(names->'common') AS name
WHERE name->>'language' = 'en';
```

The corresponding json path expression would be

```
SELECT id, jsonb_path_query(names, '$.common[*]?(@.language == "en").value') AS en_name
FROM test;
```

<sup>([Updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vv5kb2xl))</sup>

Comment: Thank you! The first is easier to read and the second is a 1 liner.  Are there any advantages in using either approach?

Comment: @Holly Not that I know.